# Is Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) a linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I know SVD is a linear algebra topic, but i've seen multiple times in different articles that SVD is a nonlinear function. So i don't know what to think..

Comment: Linear algebra is the study of linear transformations. However, we may study them using nonlinear tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In higher mathematics, a function is said to be linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. The process of SVD decomposition can be seen as a function, which we will call $S$, which take in a matrix and returns three matrices: $S(A)=(U,\Sigma,V)$. The three matrices that are returned have the property that $A=U\Sigma V^T$. However, given two matrices of the same size, say $A$ and $B$, $S(A+B)\neq S(A)+S(B)$. In other words, the $U$ in the SVD decomposition for $A+B$ is not equal to the $U$ in the SVD decomposition for $A$ plus the $U$ in the SVD decomposition for $B$. The same is true for the $\Sigma$ and the $V$.

Linear algebra has the moniker "linear" because all linear functions that act on vectors of finite dimension can be represented by matrices, and all matrices represent linear functions acting on vectors. However, certain aspects of linear algebra are nonlinear. For example, the function that accepts a matrix and returns its square: $f(A)=A^2$ is nonlinear because $(A+B)^2\neq A^2+B^2$ in general. So SVD is a linear algebra topic because it involves breaking up a single linear action into three simpler linear actions, but the function that takes each matrix to its decomposition is nonlinear.

Comment: Note also that this $S(A)$ is a multivalued function=)

Comment: True, you can rearrange the rows and columns of $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$ in a consistent way. Is it multivalued even beyond that?

Comment: @AlexS Yes, you can change the signs of the columns, but not arbitrarily so.

Comment: @AlexS the simpliest case, take $A=I$. The matrix $U=V^*$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix. Therefore, in some cases, we can go beyond rearrangements and multiplications by $-1$ and even make linear combinations of rows/columns.

Comment: @AlexS, if I am not wrong, in the way you analyse the problem then it is also shown that PCA is non-linear while we know that PCA is linear and for example t-SNE is labeled loosely speaking as non-linear PCA.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit There's not really any analysis here, I just defined linearity, and asserted that SVD does not satisfy it. But if you disagree, I invite you to take the SVD of two random matrices, $A=U_1\Sigma_1 V_2^\ast,$ and $B=U_2\Sigma_2V_2^\ast.$ Does $A+B=(U_1+U_2)(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2)(V_1+V_2)^\ast$?

Comment: By analysis I mean your line of reasoning. The problem is that at the level of matrices (A,U,Σ,V) SVD could be considered a non-linear function but at the level of the elements of the matrices (a11, a12, ..., u12, u12, ..., σ11, σ12, ..., v11, v12,...) is linear. By the latter I mean that if you do the multiplications of the elements of the matrices U, Σ, V then it is obvious that S(A+B) = S( [a11, a12, ...] + [b11, b12, ...]) = S([a11, a12, ...]) + S([b11, b12, ...]) = S(A) + S(B) (see also here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/40260/45610)

Comment: Any thoughts on my argument?

Comment: I disagree. Whether you break it down into elements or not, you are still saying $S(A+B)=S(A)+S(B)$, but that is simply not true. Try it, you will see.

In fact, if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unitary, then $U_1+U_2$ is in general not unitary, so $S(A)+S(B)$ is not the SVD of *any* matrix.

Comment: For instance, the singular values of $A$ are equal to the singular values of $-A$. If $A$ is a matrix whose singular values are all nonzero, then the singular values of $A$ plus the singular values of $-A$ are also nonzero. But the singular values of $A+(-A)$ are the singular values of the zero matrix, which are all zero. So clearly $S(A+(-A))\neq S(A)+S(-A)$.

Comment: I find your examples rather weak but they impelled me to think about why my argument maybe (or actually is) false. Regarding your first example, I cannot see how what you write is right. We are talking about S(A+B) = S(A) + S(B) and it is obvious that this does not mean necessarily that U(A+B) = U(A) + U(B) so I cannot see how the fact that "then U1+U2 is in general not unitary" is a problem for S(A+B) = S(A) + S(B). Regarding you second example, I think that it is correct but in principle the fact that a hypothesis does not hold for some extreme cases

Comment: does not mean that it does not hold for the main bulk of cases. However, I think that my whole confusion stems from the fact that there are two different definitions of linearity. Definition 1 has to with functions of polynomial(s) of up to 1 degree and Definition 2 has to do with linear mappings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function). As far as I understand, the one definition is essentially independent of the other. Does this make sense?

Comment: 1) $S(A+B)=S(A)+S(B)$ means that if $A$ and $B$ have singular value decompositions $A=U_1\Sigma_1V_1^\ast$ and $B=U_2\Sigma_2V_2^\ast$, then $A+B$ has the singular value decomposition $A+B=(U_1+U_2)(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2)(V_1+V_2)^\ast$. So $U_1+U_2$ has to be unitary. (2) I gave one example, true, but I still encourage you to try it on other pairs of matrices. Does it work? (3) We do use linear in different ways. In higher mathematics, we almost always use the second one, and that is the one I am using here.

Comment: @poetemaudit I am curious, do you know of any pair of matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $S(A+B)=S(A)+S(B)?$ Because I cannot think of one.

Comment: Haha, I did not test any specific examples (there must be some) but I know that many people consider SVD as linear (see also: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/40260/45610) and in this sense the whole issue is probably originated from a conflation of the two different definitions of linearity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function).